# protobuf-net: Inheriting custom collection

Tags: c#, protobuf-net

I've a custom collection, which is a simple implementation encapsulating `List<>`:

```
[DebuggerDisplay("Count = {Count}")]
[Serializable()]
[ProtoInclude(100, typeof(SimpleTreeNodeList<>))]
public class SimpleList<T> : IList<T>, ICollection<T>, IEnumerable<T>, ICollection
{
  ... all methods redirect to a private List<T> ...
}
```

The reason for this is that I need to override the Add method, which isn't possible for a standard List. I need to create a tree, and the collection contains a list of children. When addin an element this the collection, I need to bind it to the parent.

So, I'm inheriting this `SimpleList<T>` class in `SimpleTreeNodeList<>`

If I serialize / deserilalize a `SimpleList<T>`, it works like a charm.
But if serialize / deserilalize a `SimpleTreeNodeList<T>` it doesn't work : no error, but the collection is empty when deserialized.

I don't understand why, as for other type it works correctly ?
I've read I've to set `ProtoInclude` attribute on the base class, it's what I've done but still the same problem

This is the implementation code:

```
[CollectionDataContract(IsReference = true)]
[Serializable]
[ProtoContract]
public class SimpleTreeNodeList<T> : SimpleList<SimpleTreeNode<T>>
{
    #region CTor
    public SimpleTreeNodeList()
        : base()
    {
    }
    public SimpleTreeNodeList(int capacity)
        : base(capacity)
    {
    }
    public SimpleTreeNodeList(SimpleTreeNode<T> parent)
    {
        this.Parent = parent;
    }
    #endregion

    [IgnoreDataMember]
    [ProtoMember(1, AsReference = true)]
    public SimpleTreeNode<T> Parent { get; set; }


    public override void Add(SimpleTreeNode<T> node)
    {
        base.Add(node);
        node.Parent = Parent;
    }

    public void AddRange(IEnumerable<SimpleTreeNode<T>> collection) 
    {
        foreach (var node in collection)
            this.Add(node);
    }


    public override void Insert(int position, SimpleTreeNode<T> node)
    {
        base.Insert(position, node);
        node.Parent = this.Parent;
    }

    public override void InsertRange(int position, IEnumerable<SimpleTreeNode<T>> nodes)
    {
        base.InsertRange(position, nodes);
        foreach (var node in nodes)
            node.Parent = this.Parent;
    }

    public SimpleTreeNode<T> Add(T Value)
    {
        SimpleTreeNode<T> node = new SimpleTreeNode<T>(Parent);
        node.Value = Value;
        base.Add(node);
        return node;
    }

    public void Sort(Comparison<T> comparison)
    {
        this.Sort((x, y) => comparison(x, y));
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return "Count=" + Count.ToString();
    }
}
```

My simple test case:

```
[Test]
public void TestSimpleTreeNodeListSerialization()
{
    var data = new SimpleTreeNodeList<string>();
    data.Add("Un");
    data.Add("Deux");
    data.Add("Trois");

    var path = Path.GetTempFileName();
    try
    {

        File.WriteAllBytes(path, serialize(data));

        var data2 = deserialize<SimpleTreeNodeList<string>>(File.ReadAllBytes(path));

        Assert.IsNotNull(data2);
        Assert.AreEqual(3, data2.Count);
        for (int i = 0; i < data.Count; i++)
        {
            Assert.AreEqual(data[i].Value, data2[i].Value);
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        if (File.Exists(path))
            File.Delete(path);
    }
}


private byte[] serialize<T>(T data)
{
    var formatter = Serializer.CreateFormatter<T>();
    using (var stream = new System.IO.MemoryStream())
    {
        formatter.Serialize(stream, data);
        return stream.ToArray();
    }
}

private T deserialize<T>(byte[] data)
{
    var formatter = Serializer.CreateFormatter<T>();
    using (var stream = new System.IO.MemoryStream(data))
    {
        return (T)formatter.Deserialize(stream);
    }
}
```

Comment: Interestinng - I'll have to run it in a debugger to comment

Comment: Ok, Ty. I've put the SimpleList implementation there so you have the exact code : http://rextester.com/NPM28687 There is nothing new, it's just an exact copy of List<T>

Answer (score 0):

I’ve faced the same problem. If change the expression in DebuggerDisplay to constant, then it works.
from
[DebuggerDisplay("{Object.Property}")]
to
[DebuggerDisplay("test")]

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).